# Cucumber: How to run the After hook only once after all examples in scenarion_outline

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a scenario_outline which tests login screen of a website.

```
Scenario_outline:
    Try to login
    Verify login

    Examples:
    | User  | Pass   |
    | user1 | pass1  |
    | user2 | pass2  |
```

I want to be able to start the web page at the beginning and close if after all examples are done.

Running the Before hook is easy

```
Before do
    $start ||= false
    if ! start
        #start web page
        $start = true
    end
end
```

But how do i run my After hook only once after all scenarios are done?

```
After do
    #close web page
end
```

The above example simply closes the web page after the first example and causes the rest to fail. I cannot apply here what i did with the `Before` hook unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the rest of the tests are failing is because your After method is not setting your global back to false:

```
After do
    #close web page
    $start = false
end
```

I don't believe there is an AfterScenario hook. But in your situation, if you want the browser open for the entire Scenario Outline, I would consider using a regular Scenario and cucumber table. The will share the browser session across each test case.

FYI: There is also an at_exit hook. It's purpose is running some code after all tests.

at_exit do
  #close web page
end

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#global-hooks

Comment: If the `after` hook will set `$start` to `false` again, it will open a browser instance for every example, which is exactly what i want to avoid. But the `at_exit` hook does exactly what i need. thx.