# Is there any way to execute a function after execution of all scenarios in Ruby, Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber

Very similar to @aftersuite in testNG. I have an Gsheet API which needs to perform only once all execution is over. I am not using any testNG or JUnit lab.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar question here [at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874866/cucumber-how-to-run-the-after-hook-only-once-after-all-examples-in-scenarion-ou)

It seems you can use the `at_exit` hook, but there are some issues with that: if you use it the cucumber `at_exit` code is not run, so you have to call that explicitly yourself.

Comment: This is not working out for me. Thanks. Is there any other way to handle this.